# C# best practice: "break" from within Action<> callback called in a loop?

Tags: c#, loops, callback, action, break

I had to write my own foreach method for various reasons. This resembles an IEnumerable foreach statement:

```
public void ForEachEdge(in Vertex vertex, Action<Edge> callback)
{
    var edge = GetEdge(vertex.BaseEdgeIndex);
    do
    {
        callback.Invoke(edge);
        edge = GetEdge(edge.GetNext(vertex.Index));
    } while (edge.Index != vertex.BaseEdgeIndex);
}
```

I'm using it like so but I wish to be able to "break" out of the entire loop:

```
ForEachEdge(edge.Vertex0Index, (e) =>
{
    if (inEdge.AreConnectingSameVertices(e))
    {
        // break out of inner while loop here ...
    }
});
```

What would be best practice to break?

1. Return a status value?
2. Pass a "ref bool stopEnumerating" parameter in? (requires class instance to wrap it in, right?)
3. Your thoughts ...

I'm mostly concerned about what end users (developers) would expect in such a case.

Comment: Even though it's not async, using a `CancellationToken` fits into the concept here

Comment: Maybe its also bearable to have a Func<bool> passed along to check if your condition is met.

Comment: CancellationToken seems like it but ... why do all the samples have to be so contrieved? Pointers to a very barebones example would be nice.

Comment: 1 is good, 2 is a smell.

Comment: Predicate<T> seems like it might also do the job.

Answer (score 0):

the ref parameter method won't be as clean as a return value indicating continuation status.  You would have to switch to a `Func<Edge, bool>`

```cs
Func<Edge, bool> callback;
...
if (callback.Invoke(edge)) {
   /// do your break logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided that (for now) I'll go with a Predicate<> rather than Action<>:

```
public void ForEachEdge(in Vertex vertex, Predicate<Edge> callback)
{
    var edge = GetEdge(vertex.BaseEdgeIndex);
    do
    {
        if (callback.Invoke(edge))
            break;
        
        edge = GetEdge(edge.GetNextRadialEdgeIndex(vertex.Index));
    } while (edge.IsValid && edge.Index != vertex.BaseEdgeIndex);
}
```

Which makes the user's code look like this:

```
ForEachEdge(edge.Vertex0Index, e =>
{
    if (inEdge.AreConnectingSameVertices(e))
    {
        // found it, do something, then exit loop
        return true;
    }
    
    // continue with next item
    return false;
});
```

The nicest thing about this solution: both Predicate<> and Action<> variants can exist side-by-side! User either returns true/false from the predicate, or does not return anything and thus uses the Action<> version, like so:

```
ForEachEdge(edge.Vertex0Index, e =>
{
    if (inEdge.AreConnectingSameVertices(e))
    {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Purrfect! :)

Comment: Probably won't matter but, the result of `Predicate<T>` is not covariant whereas the result  of `Func<T, TResult>` is. Since, this will be a `bool` the difference is moot.

Comment: Well, it made me search for "wuuuut in the name of see-sharp was covariance again?". And no, it really does not matter. :)